# Algorithm to find the filter to which a record belongs

Tags: database, algorithm

I have a set of 3 parameters each can take 3 values
eg.

```
paramerets   value1    value2       value2
country      india      US          UAE
language     hindi      english     urdu
currency     Rs         Dollar      Dinar
```

based on above i have saved records like

> ```
> Name  country   language   currency 
> A     india     hindi       Rs 
> B     US        hindi       dollar 
> C     UAE       english     Rs. 
> D     india     english     Rs.
> ```

Plus i have a few filters declared as follows:

```
Filtername                  country          language         currency
Dont_care_filter             Any               Any             Any
A_Bit_Stringent_filter     India,UAE        hindi,english      Rs.
Unique_filter                India            hindi            Rs.
```

Now I need an algorithm to find the perticular filter a record belongs to?
( I case a record belongs to more than one filters it should be related to the more stringent filters ie having fewer number of values for each parameter )

what I have thought till now is represent these values of different params in form of ascii codes.
And what i need...
Is a hashing algorithm that can map one to many values ? i.e. I feed param values of one record, it matches with the precalculated hashes of all the filters declared and gives me the filer which contains the param values of the record.

Comment: Which filter would be more stringent: (Country: India; Language: Hindi,English; Currency: Rs) or (Country: India,UAE; Language:English; Currency: Rs)? You need to define what you mean my stringent. Also, your database is not normalized. Instead of having value1, value2, value3 in a single record, you should have them in multiple records. Moreover, country, language and currency should be in different tables. Anyway, once you define what stringent means, I will be able to post a solution.

Comment: Hey Tarik, more stringent filter means a filter that lets lesser records pass through.  In the given example "Unique filter" is the most stringent, and the "Dont care filter" is the least.

Comment: I understand that. But again, how do we judge? Example of two filters: (Country: India; Language: Hindi,English; Currency: Rs) and (Country: India,UAE; Language:English; Currency: Rs). Which one is more "stringent"?

Comment: Why not just store this in a database and use views?